# How to get number of cores of VM in azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to find an api or Microsoft inbuilt functions which can help me retrieve the number of cores in a particular VM

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no straight forward way to get this information.

As far as REST API go, you would need to make 2 API calls:

1. **Get Virtual Machine**: First API you would need to call is get the details about your VM using [`Virtual Machines - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get). The properties that are of interest to you are the [`location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#virtualmachine) of the VM and [`VM Size Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#virtualmachinesizetypes).
2. **Get Resource SKU**: This is the next API you would need to call using [`Resource Skus - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list). This will give you the details about all the VM SKUs. Now this is going to be a very long list and unfortunately very limited filtering capability is available (at least at the time of answering this question). Only filtering capability available is that by location (that's why getting location information in the 1st step is important).

Once you get the list of all available SKUs, you will need to first filter out by `resourceTypes` where the value is `virtualMachines` and `name` where the value is the VM Size Type obtained in the 1st step.

Once you do that, the number of cores can be obtained in `vCPUs` attribute under `capabilities` property.

Comment: Yup this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/vmSizes?api-version=2019-07-01
```

edit: if you need it for the running VM you need to [get the hardware profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#hardwareprofile) of the VM and use that first call to determine the number of cores. But its kinda static, so you might as well hardcore the results

Comment: This API is deprecated so may not work in future. Better to use List Resource SKUs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list.

Comment: Do you know how i can use filter parameter in the api since if i call the resource sku api it returns a large json which mostly is not needed. I only need for one resource

Comment: using the filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list#lists-all-available-resource-skus-for-the-specified-region

Comment: Unfortunately filter only works for location in this API 

Comment: I wanted the syntax for a filter if possible. I know i can apply a filter but i am not able to find a page which lists all the available filters

Comment: This api lists the skus which I can use in a subscirpition it does not give me the specs of a VM

Comment: right, like i mentioned in the answer (you just need to read it) you need to get the vm first and look at the vm hardware profile