# Query number of cores per vm using AZ GRAPH

Tags: azure, powershell

as of this moment in the organization, an automatic report is running on all resources. The report is running in POWERSHELL
and uses FORECH on FORECH to reach each machine to collect information

I was asked to optimize and refactor the script in order for it to be use  the az graph search.
I manage to collect all the data, except for the number of cores per machine

```
Resources 
| join kind=leftouter (ResourceContainers | where type=='microsoft.resources/subscriptions' | project subscriptionName=name, subscriptionId) on subscriptionId
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| extend HUBEnabled = iff(isempty(tostring(properties.['licenseType'])), "No", "Yes")
| extend osType =  tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType)
| extend VMSize =  tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
| extend VMStatus =  tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus)
| extend nics=array_length(properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces)
| extend vCPUs =  tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties.minVCPUCount)
| extend OSName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName)
| extend Location = tostring(location)
| extend vCPU = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties)
| mv-expand nic=properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces
| where nics == 1 or nic.properties.primary =~ 'true' or isempty(nic)
| extend nicId = tostring(nic.id)
| join kind=leftouter (
    Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces'
    | extend ipConfigsCount=array_length(properties.ipConfigurations)
    | mv-expand ipconfig=properties.ipConfigurations
    | where ipConfigsCount == 1 or ipconfig.properties.primary =~ 'true'
    | project nicId = id, privateIpAddress =  tostring(ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress))
| join kind=leftouter (
    Resources
    | where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets"
    )
on nicId
| project VMName = name, computer_name=OSName, VMSize, vCPU ,  Location,  osType , VMStatus , Private_IP=privateIpAddress , HUBEnabled , subscriptionName ,  subscriptionId ,  resourceGroup
```

for some  reason  | extend vCPU = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties) return empty value

Comment: When i try to run the above query in resource graph explorer execution failed stating that `join` operator is missing `on` clause in your 2nd left outer join can you check the query once

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

when tried with query

```
vmCore=tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties.NumberOfCores)
```

But not able to get number of cores .

[image]

Tried with ***properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties***

***Graph query:***

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| project name, properties.vmId, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType,properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize,properties.hardwareProfile.vmSizeProperties
| order by ['name'] asc
```

- Everything like hardware profile is resulting in output except vm size properties are empty which includes number of cores property:

[image]

If i checked the VM in my environment. Its json doesn't have property separately for vmsize properties where it has to have number of cores.

[image]

So there is not a straight forward way for it through the graph query.

Try Initially  check the properties and then call the number of cores for each VM.

Below command gives VM size particularly.

*Command:*

```
$Myvm= Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName myrg  -Name myacctvm
```

[image]

Reference:

***Command:***

```
$MyVmZizeProperties = Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName myrg   -VMName myacctVM
```

[image]

$NumberOfCores = $MyVmZizeProperties.NumberOfCores

[image]

**Reference:** [get-number-of-cores-of-vm-in-azure | SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288569/how-to-get-number-of-cores-of-vm-in-azure) & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the detailed explanation.

Unfortunately, the requirement is to use az-graph only, (the existing code uses Get-Azure) and the whole goal is to avoid this.

Comment: For that, the vm created must have vm hardware profile , vm size properties containing numberof cores property enabled which you can see from json file that i added in the image, it may be enabled for some subscriptions according to requirement . If its not present, then its not possible to query through azure graoh